# I want to reverse a string in c with out using string functions and also to correct a string?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

> // am using visual studio and I got run-time check failure # 3 - T?
>
> // str = "Hello how are you"
>
> // reverse_str = "ouy era woh olleH"
>
> //correct_str = "you are how Hello"

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

void reverse_str(char *str)

{

    char *begin_str, *end_str, temp;
    int l, i;
    l = strlen(str);

    begin_str = str;
    end_str = str;

    for (i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)
        end_str++;

    for (i = 0; i < l / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = *end_str;
        *end_str = *begin_str;
        *begin_str = temp;

        begin_str++;
        end_str--;
    }

}

void correct_str(char *str)

{

    char *nb, *ne, temp;
    int nl, i, l;

    l = strlen(str);

    nb = str;
    ne = str;
    while (*str)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)
        {
            if (ne != ' ')
                ne++;
            else
            {
                ne = ne - 1;
                nl = ne;

                for (i = 0; i < nl / 2; i++)
                {
                    temp = *ne;
                    *ne = *nb;
                    *nb = temp;

                    nb++;
                    ne--;
                }
            }
        }
        nb = nl + 1;
        ne = nl + 1;
    }
}

void main()

{

    char str[100] = "hello world How are you";
    reverse_str(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    correct_str(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);


}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Consider the compiler warnings as errors.

Comment: your function `correct_str` has a lot of problems, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

> // am using visual studio and I got run-time check failure # 3 - T?

you confuse several times *char** and *char* or *int* in `correct_str` :

In :

> ```
>    if (ne != ' ')
> ```

where *ne* is a *char**

In

> ```
>    nl = ne;
> ```

where *nl* is an *int* and *ne* a *char**

In

> ```
>    nb = nl + 1;
>    ne = nl + 1;
> ```

where *nb* and *ne* are a *char** and *nl* an *int*

Also :

> void main()

*main* have to return an *int*

I strongly encourage you to consider the warnings produced by the compiler

---

The title says "without using string functions" but in `reverse_str` you use *strlen*, you need to replace

> ```
> l = strlen(str);
>
> begin_str = str;
> end_str = str;
>
> for (i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)
>     end_str++;
> ```

by for instance

```
begin_str = str;
end_str = str;

while (*end_str != 0)
  end_str++;

l = end_str - begin_str;
if (l != 0)
  end_str -= 1;
```